# SQL oracle query needed to fetch record

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a requirement where I have list of records in table with I'd and timestamp....I need to fetch the latest record which is 30 minutes from the latest timestamp....
Need an oracle query for same

Example

```
1      21- feb-2018 9:00
2.     21- feb-2018 8.46
3      21- feb-2018 8.48
4      21- feb-2018 8.30
15     21- feb-2018 8.25
```

Output

```
4      21- feb-2018 8.30
```

Any help please

Comment: What do you mean by "latest" timestamp?

Comment: In the above example 21- feb-2018 9:00

Answer (score 0):

If you mean at least 30 minutes, then:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by date desc) as seqnum
      from t
      where t.date <= (select max(t2.date) from t t2) - interval '30' minute
     )  t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simple do ? :

```
select t.* 
from table t
where t.date <= (select max(t2.date) from table t2) - interval '30' minute
order by date desc
fetch first 1 rows only;
```